# Conditional formatting for different groups of cells based on progress

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am in the delivery business.  Daily, we keep track of the progress of certain routes at certain time intervals.  I would like to highlight the cells if a certain % hasn't been reached.  I was thinking I would need to have those % available to base the formula off of.  So in J-M columns, I made formulas to calculate each one's % (and will probably hide those columns).

If J3's percentage is over 75%, then I want to highlight E3 a color

What's the best way I could accomplish this?  I tried using (on cell E3) =COUNTIF(J3,J3)>80%  but it's only permanently highlighting it no matter what the % is.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xGkykujthCTx_VScbjH2761osZ8VUwCYILfhFzdFKwg/edit?usp=sharing

This example has no conditional formatting, but I colored it in a way that would reflect the conditional formatting I am seeking...
[image: example]

Comment: would this reference be helpful? https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-progress-bars/

Comment: `J3>80%` or see [Use conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413),

Comment: @24601 Not a bad substitute.  I just tried it that way but that makes it so I would need to add 2 extra columns to each time update.  I'd rather have all the math and % hidden away, and just highlight the single block.

Comment: @BlindSpots wow perfect, thank you. Guess I was over thinking it.  I appreciate it.

Comment: There are so many ways to solve a problem it is tough for us to nail it perfectly.  It's always best if it is the simplest.  Simplest isn't normally my forte either ;-)